# How to reuse Stream after performing one operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to find out `String`s starting with a particular character using the same `Stream` twice, but the second `Stream` operation is throwing an exception. How can I re-use the `Stream`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("abc", "aef", "bcd", "bef", "crf");
    stream.filter(s -> s.startsWith("a")).forEach(System.out::println);;
    stream.filter(s -> s.startsWith("b")).forEach(System.out::println);;
}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$StatelessOp.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.filter(Unknown Source)
    at StreamExp.main(StreamExp.java:13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call any terminal operation the stream is closed, You could use stream supplier to construct a new stream

```
Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier =
            () -> Stream.of("abc", "aef", "bcd", "bef", "crf");

            streamSupplier.get().filter(s -> s.startsWith("a")).forEach(System.out::println);
            streamSupplier.get().filter(s -> s.startsWith("b")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't perform a terminal operation such as `forEach` twice on the same `Stream`.

You have other alternatives. For example, you can produce a `Map<Character,List<String>>` in which the input `String`s are grouped by their first character :

```
Map<Character,List<String>> groups = 
    Stream.of("abc", "aef", "bcd", "bef", "crf")
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s->s.charAt(0)));
```

This will result in the following `Map` :

```
{a=[abc, aef], b=[bcd, bef], c=[crf]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a logic OR to combine your streams into only one stream:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("abc", "aef", "bcd", "bef", "crf");
        stream.filter(s -> s.startsWith("a") || s.startsWith("b")).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```